# Program shows memory leak, even after using free()

Tags: c, malloc

I am new to `malloc()` and been reading my books and some tutorials about it. Now that I have written my assignment, it's required that you do not have any memory leaks.

This is a piece of my code how I have written it in main:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
int main()
{   
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //Kallas för randomisera ett nummer tidsmässigt
    struct CardDeck * deck; //Dynamiskt allokerad array
    int index;
    int suit_index;
    /*int i;  kan användas om man vill loopa kortleken*/
    deck = (struct CardDeck *)malloc(sizeof(struct CardDeck)); //Bör bara användas en gång med tanke på att vi bara har en pekare under vår struct i cardeck
    deck->last_Index = 0; //Pekar på senaste indexen för att se så att kortleken är full. 
    for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NR_OF_SUITS; suit_index++)    //Loopar 4 (avser färgerna)
        for (index = 0; index < COLOR_SIZE; index++) //Loopar 13 gånger för varje värde i kortleken
        {
            deck->cards[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].suit = suit_index;
            deck->cards[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].value = index;
        }
    /*for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    printCards(deck);
    }  Om man vill loopa igenom hela kortleken (sorterad) så finns den möjlig*/

    shuffleCards(deck->cards); 
    play(deck);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    free(deck);
}
```

As you see, I used `free(deck)` at the bottom, is it something that I am missing or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Why does `int main() {printf("AAA\n"); return 0; printf("BBB\n");}` print AAA but not BBB?

Answer (score 6):

Your `free()` statement is after `return`, do you think it executes? You can try formatting your code carefully and then this kind of mistake might be avoided.

Comment: Oh thank you!

Because this code comes along when i put it after the return "Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->"

However when i put it before the return, it doesnt say anything?

Comment: But this is what happens when i use it before the return:

The thread 0x420c has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Comment: Is there a chance you free the pointer in `play()`?

Comment: Yes i do free the pointer in play, so how do i make it work without doing that?

Comment: You can't free it twice. The memory leak must be originated somwhere else or by another reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you attempt to call `free()` after the `return` statement.

Once the execution reach the unconditional `return` statement, the control will return to the caller and any statement placed after the `return` statement will be *unreachable* code. So, essentially, your call to `free()` does not get a chance to execute, at all.

To quote the standard, chapter §6.8.6.4

> A `return` statement terminates execution of the current function and returns control to
>   its caller. [...]

So basically, your `free()` does not get a chance o free-up the dynamically allocated memory, resulting in a memory leak.

You need to call `free()` *before* the `return` statement, like

```
. . . . 
free(deck);
return 0;
```